# How to convert this multiple if else into a formula?

Tags: lightning, javascript, formula, case, formula-field

How can I convert this classic syntax of a multiple if&else :

```
if (days < 1) {
    (...)
} else if(days >= 1 && days < 2 ) {
    (...)
} else {
    (...)
}
```

Into a Salesforce formula ?

Answer (score 2):

First, one common thing about this sort of logic is that you don't need to check if `days >= 1` if you already checked that `days < 1` (because, logically, if it were less than 1, the next part wouldn't execute, and if you reach that condition, is is obviously more than 1). This can be important in formulas because of the compiled-size limit.

Generally speaking, you use the same construct, but the IF statements need to be nested:

```
IF(Days < 1,
  "Less than 1",
  IF(Days < 2,
    "Less than 2",
    "2 or more"
  )
)
```

You can expand this for as many as you need:

```
IF(Days < 1,
  "within a day",
  IF(Days < 7,
    "within a week",
    IF(Days < 30,
      "within a month",
      IF(Days < 366,
        "within a year",
        "more than a year"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved it with this simple template :

[image]

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Delivery_Date__c )), IF(Logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false) , NULL)
```

From this website : https://www.tech-vision.us/salesforce-the-easiest-way-to-write-if-formulas/